# How to get form data from HTML page using c++

Tags: c++, html, cgi

How do I get form data from HTML page using c++, as far as the basics of post and get?

**EDIT:** CGI is using apache 2 on windows, I got c++ configured and tested with with apache already.

Comment: In which settings? CGI? WSGI? FCGI? Apache, IIS?

Do give us a hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to access form data from an HTTP request is via [CGI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface). This involves reading environment variables which is done using the [getenv](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/getenv/) function.

Answer (score 2):

First of all take a look at [webtoolkit](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt#/).
You might want to use that to make your life easier.
Second you can read about network protocols.
Third take a look at your webserver docs, they might provide such interface to create a [deamon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_(computer_software)) that will allow you to read the HTTP socket and the data that is sent over it.

On another note next time you write a question try to elaborate as much as possible.
Explain the use case and provide a test case.

Answer (score 1):

You may use CgiCC library that gives you want you are looking for. You may also try some C++ web framework like CppCMS.